# How do I pack a transactions in Python and push to RPC?

Tags: rpc

I am trying to write a python script to call my test network and create accounts and push transactions.

Is there any good RPC examples of creating and pushing transactions.  The examples I found stop short of making the whole transaction.

Example code.  I get invalid packed transaction when calling this:

```
tx_test ="{\"actions\": [{\"account\": \"eosio\", \"name\": \"test\", \"authorization\": [{\"actor\": \"eosio\", \"permission\": \"active\"}], \"data\": { \"creator\": \"eosio\", \"name\": \"test\", \"owner\": { \"threshold\": 1, \"keys\": [{ \"key\": \"EOS7Zw9q1J6VpSf7wFXnxPSUH3Pbgj2LiX3woKCWvxU6VerE3tCVX\", \"weight\": \"1\" }], \"accounts\": [], \"waits\": []}, \"active\": { \"threshold\": \"1\", \"keys\": [{ \"key\": \"EOS7Zw9q1J6VpSf7wFXnxPSUH3Pbgj2LiX3woKCWvxU6VerE3tCVX\", \"weight\": \"1\" }], \"accounts\": [], \"waits\": [] }}}]}"

tx_test = "[" + tx_test + ", [\"" + public_key + "\"]," + "\"" + chain_id + "\"]"


surl="sign_transaction"

payload = tx_test
print(tx_test)

response = requests.request("POST", wurl + surl, data=payload)
print(response.text)
```

Comment: you can try eosnewyork's eospy

Comment: https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/reference#push_transaction

Comment: @JimmyGuo I have put code together.  I am running this in my own test net.  I know get this error:  Error', 'error': {'code': 3050000, 'name': 'action_validate_exception', 'what': 'Action validate exception', 'details': [{'message': 'Unknown action buyrambytes in contract eosio', 'file': 'chain_plugin.cpp', 'line_number': 1643, 'method': 'abi_json_to_bin'}, {'message': 'code: eosio, action: buyrambytes, args: {"payer":"eosio","receiver":"testtesttest","bytes":8192}', 'file': 'chain_plugin.cpp', 'line_number': 1654, 'method': 'abi_json_to_bin'}]}}

Comment: @btclibertarian check out that if your test net have added the eosio system contract

Comment: @JimmyGuo Yes.  I do the following when building my system: cd /eos/contracts/eosio.system && eosiocpp -o eosio.system.wast eosio.system.cpp     I can create accounts with my cleos command line so I know everything is in the system.  However, I do not stake EOS in my cleos command line test system.  Just like the training site.